# Subring of the field of rational numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, inverse, principal-ideal-domains

> Let $R=\{a\cdot2^n\mid a,n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ be a subring or the field of rational numbers $\mathbb Q$.
>
> i) What kind of elements are invertible in $R$?
>
> ii) Prove that $R$ is a principal ideal ring, that is, every ideal in $R$ is principal.

For (i) I came to a conclusion that whenever $a=1$, the elements are invertible. Is it right? or it might be hold for any odd a? (I doubt as 1/a is an integer only when a=1..)

For the (ii) I assumed that $J$, which is not 0, is an ideal in $R$. Thus, there exists $c\cdot2^k$ in $J$… and $c$ should be the minimal positive odd integer? but how to show it?

Comment: You cannot prove that $R$ is a principal ideal ring by assuming that you already have a principal ideal. You need to start with an _arbitrary_ ideal and then show that it has to be principal. **Hint:** show that the ideal is uniquely determined by its intersection with $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thanks for pointing this out, in my notes I meant an arbitrary ideal, it was a mistype.

Comment: (i) What about $a=-1$?

Comment: @user I forgot about -1. {1,-1} then the only options?

Comment: As we work inside the field $\Bbb{Q}$, an element is invertible in $R$, iff its inverse in $\Bbb{Q}$ is also an element of $R$. An element $r$ of $R$ is of the form $r=a\cdot 2^n$, so its inverse is $r^{-1}=a^{-1}\cdot 2^{-n}$. For which combinations of $a$ and $n$ is $r^{-1}$ an element of $R$?